# Reduction — Do they work for unrelated problems?

Tags: complexity-theory, reductions

I think I understand that a P class problem is reducible to an NP class problem (P≤NP).

I´d like to understand if I need to figure out a potential algorithm which could solve the NP class problem to know if it can be used as a subroutine for a P class problem.

So for example, if I ask you if the problem from class P —sum of integers— is reducible to a problem of class NP —Clique graph problem—, how would you reply to it?

Is this a valid reduction as the more complicated Clique problem is NP and the easier problem sum of integers is a P problem even though they deal with different math branches (one being algebra and the other one being graph theory)?

Comment: You might want to double-check which direction of reduction you are asking about.  Also, saying "problem P (sum of integers)" - P is not a problem, it is a class of problems (and labelling a problem P is super-confusing since P usually means the class of problems solvable in polynomial time).  Anyway, one way to figure out if such a reduction exists is to try to find one, and see if you can come up with one.

Comment: @D.W.: Thanks, I have updated my question. If you like send me an answer and I´ll accept it. I guess I would not be able to find a reduction as the two problems are unrelated.

Comment: Be careful with terminology. "a P class problem is reducible to an NP class problem" -- do you mean that there *are* such problems, or that the statement holds true for *all* pairs?  "P≤NP" -- what does that mean?

Comment: You should be careful with calling problems 'unrelated'. In mathematics (and by extension, in computer science) problems that _appear_ completely different at first glance quite often turn out to be related in some form.

Comment: Thanks, I am not really an expert at math, that´s why I asked in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a problem $X$ that is in P, then you can construct a polynomial time reduction to *any* problem $Y$ in NP (or in 'any' other class of problems*). This is possible, as our 'reduction' is allowed to spend polynomial time on the input of $X$, so it can simply determine whether a given input $I$ for $X$ is a 'yes'-input in polynomial time and map to a trivial input for $Y$ with the same truth-value.

---

*: To be precise, any decision problem such that we can find at least one 'yes'-instance and one 'no'-instance, which holds for pretty much any interesting decision problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is for some homework I have to do. I´ll tell the professor that I had to ask here and you kindly offered some help.