# Linear time reduction equivalence

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, runtime-analysis, polynomial-time

I have to show if the following statement is true or false. Suppose we have two problems $A$ and $B$. We want to know whether the following is true:

> If $A \le_p B$ and there is an algorithm which solves $B$ in linear time, then there is an algorithm which solves $A$ in linear time as well.

So we recently started with polynomial time reductions and I am not sure what to do for this problem.

Comment: A hint: is there any good reason why _linearity_ of the algorithms is preserved under _polynomial_ time reductions? If so, try to use that for a proof. If not, try some examples and see if you can find a counterexample. In case you're still stuck, perhaps [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/85649) can shed light on another approach.

Comment: Construct a P-complete problem solvable in linear time (you can use padding to improve the running time), and use the time hierarchy theorem.

Comment: I would use as a counter example the factorizing problem. Multiplyling two prime numbers will be in $P$ where factorizing a given integer to its prime factors is in $NP$

Comment: It is not known how to multiply two prime numbers in linear time, and it is not known that factorization is any harder than multiplication.